# mocktio verify parameter order

Tags: java, testing, mockito

I have been searching for this for a while with no answer.

lets say I have a class **Service** which uses **Calc** a dependency

**Calc** has a method divide

```
public void divide(int a,int b)
```

and **Service** uses it like so

```
public void serviceAMethod{
//do somehting
a=getA();
b=getB();
calc.divide(a,b);
}
```

and my test looks like this

```
@Test
public void serviceAMethod_callsCalc(){
   verify(calcMock).divide(a, b);
}
```

this passes, but if I go to **Calc.divide** and change the signature to

```
public void divide(int b,int a)
```

it still passes

how do i test that the correct arguments are passed in correct order?

Edit:Does not necessarily have to be with Mockito, how do I make this test more resilient ?

Comment: Argument captors https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.6.9/org/mockito/ArgumentCaptor.html

Comment: Actually I'm not really sure what you are trying to do here. The method signature isn't really important for the verify method, only the method call matters. It does check if you've called calc.divide(a,b). If you change your serviceAMethod to calc.divide(b,a) it shouldn't pass

Comment: @RomanKonoval no, a and b are different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay here's my solution that I think is better than a full blown integration test

I've refactored the arguments to be a pojo

```
public class OperationRequest {
    private int firstOperand;
    private int secondOperand;
    //equals and hashCode, important!
}
```

then Calc.divide becomes

```
calc.divide(OperationRequest request);
```

and the assertion

```
verify(calcMock).divide(new OperationRequest(1,2));
```

this fails now if you swap the operands

Answer (score 2):

This is because the values passed into Calc.divide are still the same. Mockito verifies the passed values and not the name of the argument. So changing the order of parameters in the Calc class will not affect the test unless you change the call done in method serviceAMethod to reflect the change.

```
public void serviceAMethod() {
  //do somehting
  a=getA();
  b=getB();
  calc.divide(b,a);
}
```

Only after you change this logic (which is what you are testing) will your test fail.

You can see this if you use the actual values:

```
public void serviceAMethod() {
   a=getA(); // EG: 1 
   b=getB(); // EG: 2
   calc.divide(1, 2); // effective call
}
```

If you swap a and b in the Calc class it will still be called with values 1, 2. And you test the following:

```
verify(calcMock).divide(1, 2);
```

Comment: you are right
how to test this correctly though? mocktio notwithstanding

Comment: Assuming you have values in a, b in the test then you will have to swap them around ass well.

Comment: Probably the best option would be to write a test for method results. e.g: divide(6,2) should always return 3. If someone changes the class signature (switch a and b) it won't pass.

Comment: @Amongalen hmm yes but for users of the api Calc, I'll be injecting a mock, so it wont matter what order of params I pass

Comment: What you say is true, but the type of change you are indicating should not fail tests for serviceAMethod(). Rather the tests for the Calc class should fail. As it is the interface of this class that are changing. There is no way to detect that in the test for serviceAMethod.

Comment: @Omar Gamil what exactly do you want to test here? From my understanding you want to test whether the first argument of divide() method is a dividend and the second one is a divisor. In this case you want to write test for the calc class itself, without mocking anything.

Comment: @Amongalen i want to test that serviceA uses Calc correctly

Comment: @Amongalen OP tries to solve this problem. Tests for `serviceAMethod` where written with the assumption about the signature of `divide` (1st arg is dividend, 2nd arg is divisor). Now the signature of `divide` is changed (1st arg is divisor, 2nd is dividend) but the test for `serviceAMethod` still passes. Unit test for calc would definitely capture this, but it would be convenient if tests for clients of calc would also fail in this case as such change definitely breaks clients and requires clients to be changed.

Comment: @Roman Konoval In my opinion it's unnecessary to test the same thing on two different levels. Actually thats the whole idea of mocking - you assume that the things you depend on are working correctly and just do your thing.

Comment: @Amongalen If you have a unit test for `Calc` and you change `divide` method the way OP described you will have failure of the unit test for `Calc. You fix it and all tests a green. But you still have a problem that `serviceAMethod` is broken. So this is not the same thing. One thing is the logic of `divide` method and another thing is that clients call it correctly.

Comment: This cannot be covered with a unit test if Calc is mocked. The only way to ensure this is by not mocking Calc and calling the actual method. What you are trying to achieve is usually done in the change process. Eg: if I change this interface what impact does it have and what do I have to change.

Answer (score 0):

Tests for serviceAMethod where written with the assumption about the signature of `divide` namely that the first argument is a dividend and the second argument is a divisor.

Now the signature of `divide` is changed namely the first argument is now a divisor and the second argument is a dividend. But the test for `serviceAMethod` still passes.

Unit test for calc would definitely capture this, but it would be convenient if some test for every client of `divide` also fail in this case as such change in signature of the `divide` definitely breaks clients and requires clients to be changed.

When you change how a method interprets its parameters that would definitely require to change the clients of the method. Tests that mock `divide` cannot detect such change.

The integration test for `serviceAMethod` that uses real `Calc` would detect such change and will break. This will give you a reminder that `serviceAMethod` should be changed so it passes parameters in the other order.